# mouseleave won't trigger if cursor moved before target is visible

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a menu of pizzas and when the user hovers their cursor over one of the pies, it displays information about that pie in a div over top of it. What I've got so far works, but there's a quirk.

If you move your mouse too quickly over .infotrigger, .iteminfo isn't visible for mouseleave to fire thus leaving .iteminfo visible, which is undesirable.

You can play with it [here](http://uppercrust.gillisad.com/menu).

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {

        $('.infotrigger').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).children('.iteminfo').show(100);
        });

        $('.iteminfo').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(200);
        });

    });
```

I've searched for weeks for a solution and have come close, but it always seems to come back to my perceived need for the "this" trigger getting in the way. I used the children handler because I'm using the same classes for every item on the menu. Without it, information for every pizza on the menu would pop up. I tried a list at first but couldn't seem to get it to work. If there's a more elegant way of going about this, i'm all eyes. I'm wondering if the way I've structured the HTML is the biggest hinderance to what I'm trying to achieve.

HTML:

```
<div class="menuitem">
    <div class="infotrigger">
        <div class="iteminfo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuitem {
width:144px;
height:200px;
float:left;
position:relative;
display:block;
font-size:1.2em;
letter-spacing:.05em;
margin-left:2em;
z-index:5;
}

.menuitem p {
margin-bottom:0;
}

.menuitem img {
}

.infotrigger {
margin-bottom:-14px;
height:120px;
overflow:visible;
}

.iteminfo {
position:relative;
display:none;

width:238px;
/*height:168px;*/
margin:-140px auto 0 -47px;
text-align:left;
font-size:0.8em;
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:0;
color:rgb(110,48,21);
border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow:1px 1px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(224,201,174) 0%, rgb(254,245,224) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(224,201,174) 0%, rgb(254,245,224) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(224,201,174) 0%, rgb(254,245,224) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(224,201,174) 0%, rgb(254,245,224) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(224,201,174) 0%, rgb(254,245,224) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0, rgb(224,201,174)),
color-stop(1, rgb(254,245,224))
);
z-index:100;
}

.iteminfo img {
margin:0 0;
width:238px;
height:56px;
}

.iteminfo p {
text-align:left;
margin:0.7em 0.2em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.fb-like {
margin:0.5em auto 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

Thanks for you help. This is what a designer attempting web development looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if will do much, but try adding some stops, if not create a backup plan:

```
$('.infotrigger').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children('.iteminfo').stop(true, true).show(100);
});

$('.iteminfo').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

The backup plan, not a good idea, but try changing it to something with more local scope:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ($(".iteminfo").is(':visible') && e.target.className != 'iteminfo') {
        $(".iteminfo").hide(); //could use a timeout aswell
    }
});
```

Probably the best solution would be to just do:

```
$('.infotrigger').mouseenter(function () {
    var elm = $(this).children('.iteminfo');
    $('.iteminfo').not(elm).fadeOut(200);
    elm.show(100);
});

$('.iteminfo').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. The best solution you posted _is_ the best solution from what I can tell. I plugged it in and it worked great.

Comment: I just spent some time flying my cursor all over the page and realized that, if the cursor doesn't land on a pizza upon exiting another, the .iteminfo div sticks still. That is, if I do a horizontal swipe of the mouse, left to right, the right-most .iteminfo will stay visible. The solution posted by mqchen seems to work best. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply binding `hover` event to `infotrigger`?

```
$('.infotrigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.iteminfo').show(100);
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.iteminfo').fadeOut(200);
});​
```

I have tested, it works fine ;)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for whatever reason. The other two solutions worked for me, though. Thanks for your time.

Comment: same problem in different disguise

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**
Why not pure CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/QFJz7/

It just shows the info on hover, and for browsers that support css3 animations the info will fade in.

**Javascript**
Here is an old-school javascript solution that is slightly more verbose: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/Sbg7g/3/

It basically hides all others no matter which "pizza" the mouse leaves. Check out the jsfiddle. You only need to consider the javascript parts.

```
var triggers = $(".infotrigger");
var infos = $(".infotrigger .iteminfo");

$(triggers).each(function(index, trigger) {
    $(trigger).mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(infos).each(function(i2, info) {
            if(index === i2) {
                $(info).fadeIn(100);
            }
        });
    });

    $(trigger).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(infos).each(function(i2, info) {
            $(info).fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess my thought was more people would have a javascript enabled browser than a newer browser that supports CSS3.

I tried the javascript you posted and it worked beautifully. Thanks very much for your help with this. I apologize it took so long for me  to respond. This project got put on the back burner for a while but is no in the pipeline again.